# CSS table style calling class

Tags: css, css-tables

I have some tables on my site.

The code in the style.css has default settings
reads:

```
table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have assigned a class to my table which I don't want to use these settings:

and tried to then implement :

```
table.checkmarkarray {
border-width: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

but it does not override the other value of 
border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;

how can I override this value? without changing the default value?

Comment: Are you sure the class name is correct?

Comment: @Felix table class="checkmarkarray" yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all borders from your table, you need to change the `td` properties on top of your `table` properties.

```
table.checkmarkarray, table.checkmarkarray td {
    border: none;
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xCduD)

Comment: @LudowicL ya this actually worked, nice thanks! I wonder why table.checkmarkarray { border: none;} does not work, also can replace td with tr for the same effect?

Comment: table.checkmarkarray {border:none;} tells your table to drop its borders : and that's what it did ! However, it doesn't remove the borders that are on your cells (the `td`s), that's why there were still borders.

Comment: Your CSS reset code doesn't ask your `tr`s elements to have borders : so you don't have to delete them, since there aren't any.

Comment: you beautiful old dog :) thanks! was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `!important` property here:

```
table.checkmarkarray {
    border-width: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

or just:

```
table.checkmarkarray {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: http://www.journeywithandrew.com/world-heritage-sites-reviews-info/ look at the check marks - there is a border around them - as they are in the table. I have now used !important but still does not work.

Comment: @AndrewH Try to use `border: none` instead.

Comment: that only removes some of the borders, table.checkmarkarray, table.checkmarkarray td {
    border: none;
} took them all away. super annoying stuff working with this themes style.css - wish they used custom class for tables and stuff and not just generic calls

Answer (score 0):

You can try just add in `border: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Add below the default values in style.css:

```
table, tr, th, td {
    border: none;
}
```